# visual studio no me deja ejecutar hola mundo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy empezando con Visual Studio y C#. Empezando por el Hola mundo ya no me deja ejecutar el programa.

1. He creado un nuevo proyecto como Aplicación de consola

El codigo que aparece es el siguiente:

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Ahora no se que hacer porque en los tutoriales que veo simplemente pulsan en en el botón para mostrar el mensaje. A mi me aparece adjuntar y no se muestra la consola. Aparece un menu de **asociar al proceso**

[image: ejecutar codigo]

Los pasos que he seguido para crear el proyecto son los siguientes:

[image: crear]

[image: crear aplicacion consola]

[image: nombrar]

[image: elegir frame]

[image: resultado final]

Comment: Como has abierto el codigo? Has abierto la solución o proyecto o solamente has abierto el archivo cs? Asegurate de que el proyecto está marcado como "Set as Startup Project" también (click derecho al proyecto y marcar esa opción, deberia salir en negrita el nombre)

Comment: Reedito para mostrar los pasos que hago

Comment: Si te fijas en la ultima foto, en el explorador de soluciones no te aparece ningun proyecto vinculado a esa solución. Deberias vincular tu proyecto a esa solución o crear un proyecto nuevo y asignarlo como proyecto de inicio para que puedas ejecutarlo.

Comment: Pero si en todos los videos que veo se crea solo al utilizar la plantilla. No entiendo por que en mi caso lo crea vacío. Incluso en la documentación de Microsoft pone que se crea con toda la jerarquía de archivos al utilizar la plantilla https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-ide-orientation?view=vs-2022

Comment: No importa que te esté fallando la creación. Dale clic derecho a la solución, toca agregar proyecto existente y busca el .csproj

Comment: Vale, entonces me dice ** El SDK "Microsoft.NET.Sdk especificado no se pudo encontrar" **

Comment: "Visual Studio *no me deja ejecutar*" - Nop. Dudo mucho que Microsoft diseñe un IDE que aleatoriamente no permita ejecutar un programa de consola a un usuario novato. Parece más un error de capa 8. Creo que vale la pena vuelvas a empezar el curso introductorio e instales los workloads necesarios para tener los SDK's y versiones del framework más actuales. Todo eso está en el curso introductorio.

Comment: Independientemente a la mala formulación de la pregunta, el error capa 8 y el novato (suena mejor nuevo, que soy muy sensible), no solo van varios tutoriales en video, sino que estoy siguiendo al pie de la letra lo que dice la documentación de Microsoft.  Disponible en : https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio?pivots=dotnet-7-0 . No es complejo pese a ser un "novato" hacer una instalación siguiendo estos pasos pero el resultado es distinto. En mi caso no puedo ejecutar porque no se crea esa jerarquía de archivos como dice @Marc

Comment: La palabra "novato" no tiene nada inherentemente malo, tampoco es inapropiado en este contexto; no hay razón para discutir el término. Todos aquí fuimos novatos y seremos novatos en algo más. Dicho esto, la documentación pide instalar el workload/ la carga de trabajo **Desarrollo de escritorio de .NET**. Lo instalaste? Si no estás seguro, ejecuta el instalador nuevamente y búsca la carga de trabajo.

Comment: Si si, está instalado. De hecho he desinstalado todo 2 veces y vuelto a instalar. Estoy convencido de que lo he marcado todas las veces.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema pero no me funciona ni eliminando la ruta de dotnet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segun he visto, [no has sido el único con este problema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1163896/visual-studio-2022-doesnt-contain-project-doesnt-b).

Para solucionar este problema debes dirigirte a las propiedades del sistema, en la ventana de Variables de Entorno y buscar a ver si tienes dos paths al directorio `dotnet`:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet
C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet
```

En caso de que los tengas, debes eliminar este `C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet`.

Entonces reinicia el equipo y vuelve a crear el proyecto para ver si lo hace correctamente.

---

Para acceder a las Variables de Entorno debes dar click derecho al icono de Windows y seleccionar Sistema.

Alli en la ventana Configuración Avanzada te diriges a la pestaña Avanzado y haces clic al botón Variables de Entorno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Correcto. Muchas gracias. Al eliminar esa ruta funciona perfectamente.